# Stripe payments, adding price from Invoice model into Charges model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I want Users to be able to pay their remaining balances on Invoices, through either checkout or stripe.js. I am having trouble getting the Charges model or Controller gain access to the Invoices model or controller to have the charge reflect the correct price.

**Invoice Model:**

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :charge
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**Charge Model:**

```
class Charge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  def self.charge(amount, token)
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
      :amount => params[:amount],
      :source => token,
      :currency => "usd",
      :description => "Pay Remaining Invoice Balance"
    })
  end
end
```

**Charges Controller:**

```
before_action :amount_to_be_charged
def new
end

def create 
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer => customer.id,
    :amount => params[:amount],
    :description => 'Invoice payment',
    :currency => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end

private
  def amount_to_be_charged
    @amount = @invoice.IBalDue
  end
end
```

So, basically I want to have the `IBalDue` column of the Invoices model be accessible to the Charges, so when I click the button it reflects the correct price. Any help, I'm relatively new to rails.

Comment: I have never seen a method name with such case before? is `IBalDue` the name of a method? If use where is it defined ?

Comment: It's not a method, just data from the invoices model that will be hard-coded to the invoice.